# error in starting odoo 9

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

this is a strange problem but i installed odoo 9 from github [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/9.0) , and the port 8069 gives me an access to openerp 6 which i don't know why, i checked my odoo version and it's the 9th version. and when i use another port like 8080 it gives me this error

```
2017-08-03 12:03:26,594 6643 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2017-08-03 12:03:26,595 6643 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/menagabara/.local/share/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons', u'/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/addons']
2017-08-03 12:03:26,595 6643 INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
2017-08-03 12:03:26,677 6643 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8080
2017-08-03 12:03:37,683 6643 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2017-08-03 12:03:37,971 6643 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2017-08-03 12:03:38,072 6643 INFO ? openerp.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2017-08-03 12:03:38,079 6643 INFO menagabara openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2017-08-03 12:03:38,088 6643 INFO menagabara openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries
2017-08-03 12:03:38,236 6643 INFO menagabara openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2017-08-03 12:03:38,236 6643 INFO menagabara openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
2017-08-03 12:03:38,265 6643 INFO menagabara werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2017 12:03:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 -
2017-08-03 12:03:38,280 6643 INFO menagabara werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2017 12:03:38] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 303 -
2017-08-03 12:03:38,377 6643 INFO menagabara werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Aug/2017 12:03:38] "GET /web/login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2017-08-03 12:03:38,398 6643 ERROR menagabara werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 249, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1497, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1471, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1668, in dispatch
result = ir_http._dispatch()
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 187, in _dispatch
return self._handle_exception(e)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 158, in _handle_exception
return request._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 788, in _handle_exception
return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 183, in _dispatch
result = request.dispatch()
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 847, in dispatch
r = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 323, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 319, in checked_call
result.flatten()
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1448, in flatten
self.response.append(self.render())
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1441, in render
context=request.context)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1087, in render
return self.pool[engine].render(cr, uid, id_or_xml_id, qcontext, loader=loader, context=context)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 252, in render
element = self.get_template(id_or_xml_id, qwebcontext)
File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 174, in get_template
raise_qweb_exception(QWebTemplateNotFound, message="Loader could not find       template %r" % name, template=origin_template)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb.py", line 172, in get_template
document = qwebcontext.loader(name)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py",   line 1085, in loader
return self.read_template(cr, uid, name, context=context)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 959, in read_template
 view_id = self.get_view_id(cr, uid, xml_id, context=context)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py",  line 963, in get_view_id
 return self.pool['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_id(cr, uid, xml_id,   raise_if_not_found=True)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1009, in xmlid_to_res_id
 return self.xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(cr, uid, xmlid,   raise_if_not_found)[1]
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1001, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
 return self.xmlid_lookup(cr, uid, xmlid)[1:3]
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
 return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "<string>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup

 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/menagabara/Desktop/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 991, in xmlid_lookup
 raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
 QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login
```

and server can't be killed even when i restart the pc and clear history

```
 openerp   1416     1  0 12:30 ?        00:00:13 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin  /openerp-server --config=/etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf --logfile=/var/log/openerp-server.log
 root      6576  2708  0 14:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto openerp-server
```

I'm running ubuntu 17.04, any help?

[image]

here's my openerp-server.comfig file

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
```

Comment: Your odoo v.9 works in port 8080. And the error tell about problem in a QwebTemplate.

Comment: so how to fix this? @julivico

Comment: You have used `web.login`, which wasn't defined in Odoo. This point is somewhere in your modules. You must search and fix it. I don't know, where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your */etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf* file and the folder where you cloned the repository so that I can suggest you better

Also to kill the server you can use the command

```
sudo kill -9 *pid*
```

You will get the pid on running

```
ps -aef| grep openerp-server
```

Comment: i added the file, I'm using this and sudo kill -3 *pid*  too to kill the server but it's not working most of the time.

Comment: So in the odoo repo at: https://github.com/odoo/odoo, you see that there is and addons folder.

The "addons_path" in the openerp-server.conf file should contain the relative path of that addons folder on your system.